# Организовать функцию swap для узлов двухсвязного списка

Tags: c++, указатели, список

Здравствуйте нужно организовать функцию swap для двух узлов из двухсвязного списка. Вот мои попытки выглядят следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class List
{
   public:
   List();
   ~List();

   void push_back(double a, float* b, unsigned int c);
   int get_size();
   void clear();
   void print_list_first();
   void print_list_from_end();
   void delete_node(int index);
   void swap_list(const int index1, const int index2);
   List operator()(List obj);

private:

    class Node
    {
      public:
         double a;
         float* b;
         unsigned int c;

         Node* next;
         Node* previous;

         Node() {};

         Node(double a, float* b, unsigned int c, Node* next = nullptr, Node* 
         previous = nullptr) {
               this->a = a;
               this->b = b;
               this->c = c;
               this->next = next;
               this->previous = previous;
          }
    
    };

    int Size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

};

List::List()
{
   Size = 0;
   head = nullptr;
}

List::~List() 
{

}

void List::push_back(double a, float* b, unsigned int c)
{
    Node* current = new Node(a,b,c);
    current->next = nullptr;

    if (head == nullptr) {
        current->previous = nullptr;
        head = tail = current;
    }
    else
    {
       current->previous = tail;
       tail->next = current;
       tail = current;
    }

      Size++;
}

void List::swap_list(const int index1, const int index2)
{
    Node* first = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
    {
       first = first->next;
    }

    Node* second = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index2; i++)
    {
        second = second->next;
    }



   Node temp;
   Node* a_next, * b_next;
   a_next = first->next;
   b_next = second->next;
   temp = *first;
   *first = *second;
   *second = temp;
   first->next = a_next;
   second->next = b_next;


}

void List::print_list_first()
{
   Node* current = this->head;

   while (current != nullptr) {

      cout << current->a << " " << *(current->b) << " " << current->c << 
  endl;
      current = current->next;

  }
}

void List::print_list_from_end()
{
   Node* current = this->tail;

   while (current != nullptr) {

    cout << current->a << " " << *(current->b) << " " << current->c << endl;
    current = current->previous;

   }
}

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

List onе;
float a = 4.5;
onе.push_back(1, &a, 1);
onе.push_back(2, &a, 2);
onе.push_back(3, &a, 3);
onе.push_back(4, &a, 4);

onе.print_list_first();
onе.swap_list(1,2);
cout << endl << endl;
onе.print_list_first();
cout << endl << endl;
onе.print_list_from_end();

}
```

Проблема состоит в том что где-то ошибка с указателями возникла и в итоге при выводе списка с хвоста показывает только хвост, а если с головы до хвоста то все работает хорошо.

Специально для Harry. Вот результат роботы того метода который Вы предложили:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядят функции swap, print_list_first, print_lise_from_end :

```
void List::swap_list(const int index1, const int index2)
{
    Node* a = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
    {
        a = a->next;
    }

    Node* b = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index2; i++)
    {
       b = b->next;
    }

    if (a->previous) a->previous->next = b;
    if (b->previous) b->previous->next = a;

    if (a->next) a->next->previous = b;
    if (b->next) b->next->previous = a;

    Node* t;
    t = a->previous;
    a->previous = b->previous;
    b->previous = t;
    t = a->next;
    a->next = b->next;
    b->next = t;
}

void List::print_list_first()
{
   Node* current = this->head;

   while (current != nullptr) {

    cout << current->a << " " << *(current->b) << " " << current->c <<
        endl;
    current = current->next;

   }
}

void List::print_list_from_end()
{
    Node* current = this->tail;

    while (current != nullptr) {

      cout << current->a << " " << *(current->b) << " " << current->c << 
      endl;
      current = current->previous;

    }
}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: Хотя бы укажите, у вас односвязный или двусвязный список (а еще лучше, определение типа Node напишите)

Comment: `temp = *first; *first = *second; *second = temp;` так делать **не надо**. Надо корректировать только указатели (как вам @Harry в ответе написал)

Comment: avp, я попробовал способ Harry но код уходит в постоянный цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А кто будет обновлять указатель `prev` или как там он у вас называется?

```
void List::swap_list(const int index1, const int index2)
{
    Node* t;
    Node* a = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
    {
        a = a->next;
    }

    Node* b = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index2; i++)
    {
        b = b->next;
    }

    if (a->next != b && b->next != a)
    {
        if (a->previous) a->previous->next = b;
        if (b->previous) b->previous->next = a;
        if (a->next) a->next->previous = b;
        if (b->next) b->next->previous = a;
        t = a->previous;
        a->previous = b->previous;
        b->previous = t;
        t = a->next;
        a->next = b->next;
        b->next = t;
    }
    else
    {
        if (b->next == a) { t = a; a = b; b = t; }

        b->previous = a->previous;
        if (a->previous) a->previous->next = b;

        a->next = b->next;
        if (b->next) b->next->previous = a;

        a->previous = b;
        b->next = a;

    }

    if (head == a) head = b;
    else if (head == b) head = a;

    if (tail == a) tail = b;
    else if (tail == b) tail = a;

}
```

Comment: Harry, попробовал ваш способ но программа уходит в бесконечный цикл

Comment: Ну, я же не знаю, **как** вы пробовали - что я могу сказать? Компилируемого минимального примера нет, мне не хочется тратить час и писать большую полную программу работы со списками - которая все равно вас ни в чем не убедит...

Comment: Harry, я добавил весь код который должен помочь найти ошибку

Comment: Harry, я попробовал так как вы сказали а именно так: void List::swap_list(const int index1, const int index2)
{
 Node* a = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
 {
  a = a->next;
 }

 Node* b = head;
 for (int i = 0; i < index2; i++)
 {
  b = b->next;
 }

 

 if (a->previous) a->previous->next = b;
 if (b->previous) b->previous->next = a;

 
 if (a->next) a->next->previous = b;
 if (b->next) b->next->previous = a;

 
 Node* t;
 t = a->previous; 
 a->previous = b->previous; 
 b->previous = t;
 t = a->next; 
 a->next = b->next; 
 b->next = t;
 
 

 
}

Comment: И где тут бесконечный цикл? Если в `print_list_first` - то приведите ее код... Кстати, и `print_list_from_end` тоже.

Comment: Harry, в своем вопросе я оставил для Вас скриншот работы программы и функции swap, print_list_first, print_list_from_end.

Comment: Да, согласен - недоcмотрел, когда узлы - соседи, тогда несколько сложнее. Попробуйте новый вариант функции.

Comment: Harry, все работает спасибо вам большое